# What were Kauravas doing during geetopadesham from Sri Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, history

When Arjuna was feeling bad to fight against Bheeshma and his Guru Dronacharya, Shri Krishna tries to enlighten Arjuna by preaching Geethopadesha when they are in the middle of the war field. What were other doing-especially Kauravas, because the war was already started during that time?

Because that could be the right time to shoot an arrow on Arjuna. And it was a complete waste of time for others.

And when Shri Krishna shows Vishwaroopam to Arjuna, will others also see?

Comment: As per the rules agreed upon, they were not supposed to hit arrow on an unarmed one..till Bhishma was commander, this rule was followed I think...Kaurvas were just wondering what's happening bw Krishna n Arjuna.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The entire Geethopadesh lasted for days to clarify all the queries Arjuna had. Krishna brought the time to stand still during this entire conversation. Thus Geethopadesh seemed to be a split second exchange of information.

Krishna,you must remember is a Cunning Avtar. He could cheat with impunity in the name of Dharma. So making time to stand still is not a difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

That happened in a split second as the lord and Arjun are divine beings . It is not necessary for them to converse like humans do . They did it telepathecally . Only the initial moments of the war are described in Bhagvad Geeta , where Arjun lays down his arms . Its in this moment where the lord delivers the Geeta to him ,in a second or maybe less . Then the war commends. Therefore the entire Geeta event took place in a very small fraction of time , not disturbing other events of the war.
The lord gives Arjun divine eyes before he revealed Vishwaroopam to him . So others did not see him.

Comment: 'They did it telepathically' - if all conversations can be done telepathically, why do we need a language and a script?

Comment: Existence of a language and script doesn't make it compulsory for them to use it .

Comment: Telepathy also makes sense  because of the war environment at that time .If the lord had delivered the Geeta for all the beings on the planet to be read , then why did he reveal it only to Arjun at that moment ? He could've gathered all the Pandav warriors (if the war had not started or the warriors were not busy for some reason ).